# Can an AW*-algebra be recovered from its lattice of projections?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Can an AW*-algebra be recovered (up to Jordan isomorphism) from its lattice of projections? This is possible in the commutative/Boolean case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this follows from Theorem 4.2 in Dye's Theorem and Gleason's Theorem for AW*-algebras by Jan Hamhalter.
Link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4597

Here the statement is: given an AW*-algebra $A$ without type I$_2$ summands, and an AW*-algebra $B$, then every orthocomplement-preserving order morphism $\varphi:P(A)\to P(B)$ can be extended to a Jordan *-homomorphism $A\to B$, i.e., the complexification of a Jordan homomorphism from the self-adjoint part of $A$ to the self-adjoint part of $B$.

You can get rid of the type I$_2$ condition by splitting $A$ in a type I part and a type II/III part and use that the projections of a type I AW*-algebra completely determine type I AW*-algebras up to *-isomorphism, which is an observation of M. Ozawa. The type II/III part follows from Hamhalter's Theorem. Details can be found in Corollary 9.2.9 of http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/handle/2066/158429

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That theorem realizes an orthoisomorphism of projection lattices as a Jordan $*$-isomorphism, whereas my question was about whether one could reconstruct the algebra itself given the lattice of projections (and possibly some additional structure). However, the proof of Theorem 4.2 references [another paper by Heunen and Reyes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5778) that does just that, although what's required to get only the Jordan structure is not clear from just reading their results.